# Fuzzing services?

Tags: fuzzing, automated-testing

Are there any softwares/solutions with we can just:

- Download, start a binary/shell script

And it will automatically start to fuzz ex.: the Linux kernel, like ex.: syzkaller?

But if it would found anything it would automatically send the crash/coredump file/input of the fuzzing that caused the crash to a central place? Where volunteers could work on the patches/remove false alerts?

It would be "BOINC"-like, so if it would be so simple that people just download & run a script/binary (what would automatically upload the results), they would be glad to give many CPU resources for fuzzing.

**Related**: syzkaller found another serious bug: CVE-2017-2636

Comment: A service is something that serves you, there some easy-to-use fuzzers (AFL), and some cloud fuzzing services.  But you're talking about a massive distributed network, maybe you should include that in the title. You probably would've avoided the stray close vote

Comment: Fuzzing works against a specific target, and the recipient of the crash reports has to be able to investigate and fix the identified problems. That means that this 'service' you imagine has to be run, or at least expected, by the development team responsible for fixing the problem.